# How to make npm scripts refer to local packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working on a project and I want to use JSdoc for documentation. I have listed it in devDependencies and created a script to run it. My `package.json`looks like:

```
"scripts": {
  "doc": "jsdoc -c ./conf.json"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "jsdoc": "^3.4.3"
}
```

Cloning my project on another machine and typing `npm install` installs `jsdoc` to the `node_modules` folder.

However, when I run `npm run doc`, I get a large error, the center of which is: `'jsdoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

This is because JSdoc is installed in `node_modules` not my local path.

What is the best way to point `npm-run` commands to my locally installed modules? Also, what is the point of having dependencies such as JSdoc listed in `devDependencies` (thus installed in `node_modules`) when they can not be used from there?

Comment: What version of `npm` are you using? That should work because `npm` prepends `./node_modules/.bin/` to the search path when using `npm run` expressly for this reason. Also, my local example with your code works.

Comment: @T4rk1n I think OP is clearly running it from the project root where `package.json` (and therefore `node_modules/`) lives otherwise `npm run` wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @msanford I am using npm `3.10.9` I see the `jsdoc` binary in `./node_modules/.bin/`.

Comment: That is an old version of `npm`; we're now at 5, which brings many performance enhancements. Are you in a position to upgrade?

Comment: @msanford Weird, yeah, I will try to now. I am running node `v6.9.2` which I thought was pretty new

Comment: Nodejs is now at major version 8. Give it a shot and let us know. But that shouldn't change the behaviour in this problem...

Comment: @msanford. Wow, where have I been? Anyway, I updated (npm is now at version 5.0.3 but I still get the name issue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149717/discussion-between-msanford-and-startec).

Comment: chat link broken, thanks a lot for the dead end